# PayPal Error #10007 permission denied in DoExpressCheckoutPayment

Tags: php, paypal

I'm trying to implement PalPay service on our website. As I need feedback with payment status from the server I chose ExpressCheckout API.
My account has been verified and I generated API credentials (username, password and signature) but I still receive permission denied error on DoExpressCheckoutPayment operation like this:

```
[TIMESTAMP] => 2015%2d08%2d26T11%3a59%3a02Z
[CORRELATIONID] => 8aa6aafff01e8
[ACK] => Failure
[VERSION] => 93%2e0
[BUILD] => 000000
[L_ERRORCODE0] => 10007
[L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Permission%20denied
[L_LONGMESSAGE0] => You%20do%20not%20have%20permissions%20to%20make%20this%20API%20call
[L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
```

I'm using code from this blog http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/07/paypal-expresscheckout-with-php but I also tried to change it a little bit. For example to change the order as recommended on PayPal development site from

```
SetExpressCheckoutPayment > DoExpressCheckoutPayment > GetExpressCheckoutPayment
```

to

```
SetExpressCheckoutPayment > GetExpressCheckoutPayment > DoExpressCheckoutPayment
```

but it does not work also.

Another point that this code works fine in the sandbox but I have a problem in live instance.

I created a case in the PayPal Technical Support but at that moment answers are not so useful, maybe someone had a problem like this previously and knows how to solve it?

Also could you recommend some another php API for PayPal ExpressCheckout that works for 100%? In this case it will be possible recognize the error origin.

Thank you for answers in advance!

UPDATE: The problem is not related to the code. I follow the instruction on official web site and sent only curl requests from terminal and redirected to paypal.com manually. In that case I also got error. So, I think problem related to account settings...

Comment: Are you using the correct credentials (sandbox vs live/production)?

Comment: yes, it is first that I should check... But credentials for sandbox and live production are different and correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a Business Product Category; meaning it does not MATCH what is being sold.

1. Go to paypal.com and login
2. Click on profile/settings
3. Selling Tools
4. Business Information / update
5. Edit
6. Category & Subcategory - have to match or come close to what is being sold
7. Give a description of site
8. Save
9. Then email aup@paypal.com and let them know you have update your business category and are requesting approval for the dating site. That's it.

Comment: this is good idea. I sent en email to aup@paypal.com and described my problem. Waiting for answer...

Comment: in answer from aup@paypal.com they redirected me to the technical support. And I still do not have any answer from that service. Again waiting...

Comment: Ok, call PayPal's merchant services department at 888 215 5506 and ask them to check/change your merchant category to match what's being sold.

Comment: thanks. now I have an answer: "The problem comes from our Risk Servers at the moment due to MErchant Category". So you are right (voted up). Now I will try to change/legalize cathegory...

Answer (score 1):

This might be related to the business category of your PayPal account . You need to make sure that you have got the approval from the PayPal if you are running any dating website . If that's the case , you can follow the procedure at the below link :

https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Business-Archive/Online-dating-services-pre-approval-procedure/m-p/537240/highlight/true?profile.language=en#M2019

Comment: thank you for answer I'll ask support do I need approval like this because it is really wedding agency...